# Java hmacSHA256 with BigInteger is different compare to C#

Tags: java, c#, biginteger, sha256, hmac

Yesterday I ran into a trouble with hashing using Java and C#

I have this code in C#

```
byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("nick");
byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("key");

HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(key);
byte[] HmacBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(message);

var result = BitConverter.toString(HmacBytes);

_logger.LogInformation($">>> HMAC: " + result);
```

and this code in Java

```
byte[] message = "nick".getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] key = "key".getBytes("UTF-8");

Mac sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, sha256HMAC.getAlgorithm());
sha256HMAC.init(secretKey);

byte[] hmacBytes = sha256HMAC.doFinal(message);
            
System.out.println(">>> HMAC: " + Utils.bytesToHex(hmacBytes));
```

Both of these codes have a same result as:
`D56F32BEB288697DBC666CFCE330750240EE7252A8EACB90F30AE5EC2B6544FE`

However, If I use the message and the key with BigInteger variable, the result eventually  was different.

For specific

The key BigInteger variable:
`89846755145779207896151571317970843398423995352339053147606272151939451164346932712779779593562801986871149751592444563734853909794103626366575265329402498505873220784518950449894168432504409626921891704398413417881679930643396500380895818666783852587744861261584959964779866038266086235614583684537765854767`

The message BigInteger variable:
`105278801605955351183032861925660079240049371193037037019863031780531990060755731057393990664319512505978954889835933668032824049054190807125138251307247771506918060803959346902566451812689470408398611041302277800747341495594297701677567604614145074223483256879948522462707345079591319551080307454838134385381`

and I change in C#

```
HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(key.toByteArray());
byte[] HmacBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(message.toByteArray());

var result = BitConverter.toString(HmacBytes);

_logger.LogInformation($">>> HMAC: " + result);
```

same with Java

```
Mac sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.toByteArray(), sha256HMAC.getAlgorithm());
sha256HMAC.init(secretKey);

byte[] hmacBytes = sha256HMAC.doFinal(message.toByteArray());
            
System.out.println(">>> HMAC: " + Utils.bytesToHex(hmacBytes));
```

Then the result is very different when in C#:
`ED12EC5908E91F9F9CCE0AB8D703DC31A7DE70B20A39FC5C9A35C9193019C6D2`

and Java:
`827EE601E601B44BF09D34947A7255EE484596B8C7DBEF283A64EE5C9BDA0CD1`

What do I have to fix in Java to match with C# result?

Comment: The byte representation returned by toByteArray() is different in C# and Java. Compare the binary output in both cases and see what are the differences. To fix the issue you must make sure the key and the message are bytewise identical. For example, you could convert  the BigIntegers to String.

Comment: Thank you @roccobaroccoSC, but the code in C# can not be changed, then when I tried to convert BigInteger to String, it was still deliver the diference.

Comment: When you compare the binary output of toByteArray() in both cases, do you see any differences? Maybe it's some padding at the end that could be patched?

Comment: Dump the two outputs in the console as numbers and then use diff to compare them.

Comment: Thank you @roccobaroccoSC, but if there is any differences, we also see it in the hex result, is that right? So far now still no luck after all.

Comment: Just because the methods have the same name `.toByteArray()` doesn't mean they are the same. I wouldn't be surprised if .Net BigInteger returns the array in little-endian.

Comment: I did try to reverse the byte array too, still did not hit the match.